# I want to add server to Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: 22.04, asus, webserver, 23.04

I'm using Ubuntu 23.04. I want to add a server. The only download I found was Ubuntu 22.04. Is it possible to just change my Ubuntu 23.04 to Ubuntu Server 22.04?

I have an ASUS EX-H510M-V3  motherboard. My ASUS motherboard fought me when I was getting Ubuntu 23.04 installed, and I don't remember what I went through to make it work. Is it possible?

Comment: It's possible, it's fairly easy, but it's not the best way to learn how to run a server properly. There might be pain points for some intended uses.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you try the easy solution before you try to install Ubuntu Server the hard way.

A fresh installation of Ubuntu Server 22.04 installs very quickly. Maybe if you try to install Ubuntu Server you won't have any problems installing it as you did with installing Ubuntu 23.04. You're better off with a fresh installation of Ubuntu Server 22.04 than you would be by trying to modify an existing installation of Ubuntu 23.04 which would create endless vexing package management issues.

Comment: Agreed - LTS releases are best for server installations.